# Insert a form data to salesforce

Tags: c#-4.0, salesforce

I tried to insert form data from sitecore to salesforce using REST API.Here Below is my code sample.

```
  postAsync("https:///services/data/v45.0/composite/tree/Lead__c",JSon Data);


async static void postAsync(string url, JObject o)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var param = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
                HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(param, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format(url), contentPost).ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()))
                {

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {
                            string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;
                            Console.WriteLine(myContent);
                            Console.WriteLine(headers);

                        }
                    }
                    else { Console.WriteLine("This is doing my head in!!!!!!!!!!"); }
                }
            }
        }
```

It does not insert data to salesforce . Where I need to  use client security and security token ? How I insert data to salesforce ? Is this correct flow for inserting data to salesforce ?

Comment: I don't see any authentication here. You're required to [authenticate to the Salesforce API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&type=5) before making calls.

Comment: If I use Token ID means can I Use this same code ?. If not Please share some example code for POST Request.

Comment: I don't know what a Token ID is.

Comment: The ID, we generate using Client ID and secret Key

Comment: Can u share me  the steps that you recommand to proceed this

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here.

1. There is no authentication to Salesforce REST API. You are required to authenticate before calling Salesforce and must supply a Session Id received from the authentication process in the headers of your REST request.

   Salesforce provides examples of [authenticating](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm) in Java (but not C#) using the Web Server OAuth flow. The platform supports [many OAuth flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&type=5) and you'll need to determine which is the appropriate choice for your application. If you're doing server-to-server integration, Web Server or JWT is probably the right choice.

   If you don't want to use OAuth - and you absolutely should - you *can* get a Session Id by making a `login()` call to the [SOAP API instead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm#!). It's not recommended, though.

   Once you have the Session Id, you'll include it as an `Authentication: Bearer <Id>` header.

   The only way around authentication is exposing a custom Apex REST endpoint as part of a publicly-accessible Force.com Site. This is rarely a good design choice.
2. You're using the Composite Tree resources, which is likely more than you need to create a Lead record unless you are trying to add related records along with it. For simple record creation, just use the [Record Create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm) endpoint.